# How to re render a parent component when update database from a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying a *todo* list, every todo have an edit button that triggers a modal. From the modal (child component), you can update the description and send the new description to the database.

In the parent component there is *update* and *setUpdate* hook. I am sending both through props so that I can change the *update* value to the opposite when click save in the modal.

I was expecting the parent component to re render and make the axios call again when using *setUpdate* in the child component, this way when I click save button in modal, the list of todos will show the updated *todos*. But is not working.

I do not understand why the parent component do not re render if I am changing *update* state using *setUpdate* in the child component.

Thanks for your help.

Parent component to display todos

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import EditTodo from "./EditTodo";

const ListTodo = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      try {
        setIsPending(true);
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/todos");
        setTodos(response.data);
        setIsPending(false); // We have to changed back to false because the response finished and the data is in todos state
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message); // I am changing the error state to the message that comes from the backend if there is an error
        setIsPending(false); // I am changing back to false because the call and response ended and throw an error
      }
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/todos/${id}`);
      console.log(response.data);
      setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.todo_id !== id)); //This is the way to delete, so that the component can rerender once the todos state is changed
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };

  console.log(todos);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isPending && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      {todos && (
        <table className="table mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Description</th>
              <th scope="col">Edit</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {todos.map((todo) => {
              return (
                <Fragment key={todo.todo_id}>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{todo.description}</th>
                    <td>
                      <EditTodo
                        todo={todo}
                        update={update}
                        setUpdate={setUpdate}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.todo_id)}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ListTodo;
```

Child component to update todo

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import "./EditTodo.css";

const EditTodo = ({ todo, update, setUpdate }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo.description);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const updatedTodo = { description };
      console.log(updatedTodo);
      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:5000/todos/${todo.todo_id}`,
        updatedTodo
      );
      setUpdate(!update);
      setShowModal(false);
      // window.location = "/";
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
      >
        Edit
      </button>

      {showModal && (
        <div className="modal-background">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
              }}
              onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
            >
              <p
                style={{
                  cursor: "pointer",
                }}
              >
                x
              </p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>Input Todo</h2>
              <form className="d-flex flex-column" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="edit todo"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={description}
                  onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                <button className="btn btn-success">Save</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default EditTodo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is rerendering, but the effect that gets the list of todos is not dependent on the `update` state, so it is not be ran again when update changes. You might want to read more into how the dependency array works with the `useEffect` hook for more information about why that is, but shortly, an empty dependency array means that an effect will be called only twice, on mount and dismount.

Moving on to how to fix your problem, lift the logic that retrieves the whole list of todos and sets the state into its own function. Call that function in the effect, and pass the function to the child, call it after the update to the child is complete.

Comment: I will check the documentation about the dependencies in useEffect. Thanks!